# What does "creep around on someone" mean?

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs

What does "creep around on" mean in this phrase?

> You've been creeping around on me while you're calling me baby

Comment: Probably a non-standard (nns?) variant of ***running around, [fooling around](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fool%20around), etc.*** in the sense of *engaging in casual sexual activity* (i.e. *You say you love me, but you chase after other girls*). Where ***creeping*** implies "furtiveness, secrecy*. There's no definite syntactic principle as to which preposition to use for the object *(**me**)* in this context, so ***on*** is as good as any.

Comment: It might be literal. More context would help.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, FumbleFingers wrote:

> Probably a non-standard (nns?) variant of ***running around, [fooling around](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fool%20around), etc.*** in the sense of *engaging in casual sexual activity* (i.e. *You say you love me, but you chase after other girls*). Where ***creeping*** implies "furtiveness, secrecy*. There's no definite syntactic principle as to which preposition to use for the object *(**me**)* in this context, so ***on*** is as good as any.